# Transparent background in Unreal Engine on iOS

Tags: ios, metal, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to get a transparent background in Unreal Engine scene, so I can place another UIView behind UE4 view. I have achieved this by setting:

1. `clearColor` on `MTLRenderPassColorAttachmentDescriptor` to f.e. `MTLClearColorMake(0.0, 0, 0, 1.0)`
2. `opaque` on `CAMetalLayer` to `false`

but the background UIView blends with the UE4 view's foreground: table, chairs, and floor as if the UE4 view itself was translucent:
[screenshot with bleed-through](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1IOc.jpg).

Expected [scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYC1m.jpg), hacked by creating [a black&transparent frame of unreal view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKYGh.png).

I'm pretty new to Metal, so I cannot fully grasp where I could disable translucency computation in the code.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're shooting for here: You have a regular (non-Metal) UIView that you wish to use as a background for your UE4 view? But then you say that "the background UIView blends with the UE4 view", which makes it sound like you accomplished what you set out to do?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I've updated the original ask with additional info to make it more precise. The problem here is that the UE4 scene is somehow translucent, so when I set the background of the unreal view to be clear, my UIView bleeds through the foreground of the UE4 view. In nutshell: I want my view to be the background of the unreal view.